# How to get a percentage of how much the UIview is on screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, fadein

I am building an IOS app that starts off with a UIPageViewController when you first start using the app. I have been looking for a way to fade in an imageView depending on how far the user has swiped to the next screen. ie: When they have swiped half the screen alpha = 0.5 and when the screen has been completely swiped alpha is = 1.0?

I have tried using 'animateWithDuration' but that seems to wait till the view is fully on screen and so it shows a laggy fade in. I thought about using gestureRecognizers but pageViewController already has them and therefore I would have to override those.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply utilize the UIScrollView API to help you implement the percentage of UIView viewed/scrolled. Here's an idea how.

With UIScrollView object dragged and properly connected on its respective scene in Storyboard, and or, properly instantiated in code, go  ahead to conform your current corresponding ViewController class which you want to calculate the percentage of screen viewed to the **UIScrollViewDelegate** protocol.

E.g. `class YourCustomViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {}`

Then, somewhere inside `YourCustomViewController` class, you can implement the following code. Here's the code to achieve % of screen scrolled vertically:

```
func computePercentage(in scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let height = scrollView.contentSize.height
    let viewed = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height
    let pagePercentScrolled = viewed / height * 100.0
   // print("Percent Scrolled: \(pagePercentScrolled)")

    if pagePercentScrolled >= 50.0 && pagePercentScrolled < 100.0 {
        //Do something.
        //Example, set imageView alpha to half
        yourCustomImageView.alpha = 0.5
    } else if pagePercentScrolled == 100 {
        //Do something.
        //Example, fade in/show full imageView
        yourCustomImageView.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

In the same vein, you can alter the above slightly to calculate % of screen scrolled horizontally:

```
    func computePercentage(in scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let width = scrollView.contentSize.width
    let viewed = scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let pagePercentScrolled = viewed / width * 100.0
    //print("Percent Scrolled: \(pagePercentScrolled)")

    if pagePercentScrolled >= 50.0 && pagePercentScrolled < 100.0 {
        //Do something.
        //Example, set imageView alpha to half
        yourCustomImageView.alpha = 0.5
    } else if pagePercentScrolled == 100 {
        //Do something.
        //Example, fade in/show full imageView
        yourCustomImageView.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

Off course, you can simply combine both methods above into one. But for simplicity and readability, I separated them. 
Then you implement the UIScrollViewDelegate methods on `YourCustomViewController` like below:

```
    // MARK: Scroll View Delegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    computePercentage(in: scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    computePercentage(in: scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    computePercentage(in: scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    computePercentage(in: scrollView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **pan gesture on view** to know how much swiped on screen. Define one variable say `CGFloat xpostion`;

```
- (void)panRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  CGPoint translate = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

  if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
  {
     xpostion = translate.x;
  }
  else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
  {
     CGFloat totalXSwipe = translate.x - xpostion;

    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    CGFloat percentage = fabs(totalXSwipe)/width;
    NSLog(@"Swipe percentage %f",percentage);

    //Can use in your requirement to set as alpha value as it will be always less or equal to zero
  }
}
```

Comment: Must this function not be an @IBAction? Also are both gesture states suppose to be 'ended'? Shouldnt one be 'begin' and the other 'ended'? Lastly does this override the gesture recognizer of a UIPageViewController since I know it has a swipe gesture already build in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Paresh's Objective-C code converted into Swift:

```
var xpostion: CGFloat = 0.0
func panRecognized(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer?) {
    guard let translate: CGPoint? = gesture?.translation(in: view) else { return }

    if gesture?.state == .began {
        xpostion = (translate?.x)!
    } else if gesture?.state == .ended {
        let totalXSwipe: CGFloat = (translate?.x ?? 0.0) - xpostion

        let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

        let percentage = CGFloat(fabs(Float(totalXSwipe))) / width
        print("Swipe percentage \(percentage)")

        //Can use in your requirement to set as alpha value as it will be always less or equal to zero
    }
}
```

Happy coding!